# How to kill running processes by name from the terminal

Tags: shell

I want to kill all processes named ruby. How do I do that in one go, without manually doing `kill -9 PID` for every process?

Comment: Operating system?  I assume Linux, but add an appropriate tag for the operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple oneliner should do the trick for you:

```
ps aux | grep [s]lack | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

ps aux -> list all processes

grep -> search for a particular process by name or any identifier

awk '{print $2}' -> get the 2nd column entries from the result of `grep`
xargs kill -9 -> kill the processes.

Answer (score 0):

*killall* command may solve your problem. Please check the manual for details.